# Retrieving an object/resource from a URL

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-apps-script

I recently started using Google Apps Script to automate some Google Analytics reporting tasks. Many objects returned by Google Analytics Services have 'get' functions that return a URL in the form of a string. Actually, many Google Apps Script objects have functions that return these resource URLs, not just Google's Analytics Services. The indication is that I can somehow use these URLs to reference Google Apps resources and get objects in return, but I don't know how.

I tried simply loading one of these URLs in a browser expecting JSON or something else I could use, but received a 404 error instead. The same happened when I tried requesting the URL using a Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp.

Here's a simple example:

```js
var accountId = '0123456789'; // Pretend this is a valid account number

// Get the first WebProperty
var webProp = Analytics.Management.Webproperties.list(accountId).getItems()[0];

// ...getHref() is along the lines of "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/0123456789"
var parentHref = webProp.getParetLink().getHref();
```

The question is, what do I do with `parentHref` to get an Analytics Account object back? I feel like I'm missing something that should be fairly basic...

**Resources:**

- [Google Apps Script Reference for Analytics Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_analytics)

Comment: Have you successfully activated the API (Google Console and Apps Script)? Here a tutorial that may be helpful: [Automated Access to Google Analytics Data in Google Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2), will help you get what you need.

I add a very basic code that can serve as a guide.

```
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function authorizeGAS() {
  var result = false;
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("google");

  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?" +
                                 "scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(ScriptProperties.getProperty("YOUR_ANALYTICS_CONSUMER_KEY"));
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(ScriptProperties.getProperty("YOUR_ANALYTICS_CONSUMER_SECRET"));

  var requestData = {
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "google",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };  
  var URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles";

  try {
    result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, requestData).getContentText());
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message) Logger.log(e.message);
  }

  Logger.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After a tour through the rabbit warrens of OAuth, I managed to get a step further using your code as an example. I used the oAuth key and secret from my domain after enabling 2-legged oAuth access control and had to append key=API_KEY to the request url. Using `URL` from your example, I received a response. However, the `parentHref ` from my original example still returns a 404 error. Is it not possible to request an account object directly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not about activating the API. It's obviously active since he is already getting analytics data.

You can't just urlfetch those URLs, because you are missing the [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)-related code that goes with calling a URL that requires authentication and permission.